# Calling Game Center Leaderboard from SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-center

Hello I'm trying to call a function to show the GameCenter LeaderBoard from an SKScene but I've been unsuccessful. Here is how I call the function from a SKScene.

```
class Menu: SKScene {
  func score(sender:UIButton!) {
  GamecenterUtils.sharedGamecenterUtils.showLeaderboardOnViewController(GamecenterUtils(),leaderboardID:"myleaderID")
 }
}
```

I get a compiler error 'GamecenterUtils' is not convertible to UIViewController.
But I do this because GamecenterUtils is my CGGameCenterControllDelegate.
Here is the GamecenterUtils class than handles everything for Game Center:

```
private let _sharedGamecenterUtils = GamecenterUtils();

class GamecenterUtils : NSObject, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

    class var sharedGamecenterUtils : GamecenterUtils{
        return _sharedGamecenterUtils;
    }

    override init(){
    }

    func authenticateLocalUserOnViewController(viewController:UIViewController){
        var localPlayer:GKLocalPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer();
        if (localPlayer.authenticated == false) {
            localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(authViewController, error) -> Void in
                if (authViewController != nil) {
                    viewController.presentViewController(authViewController,animated:false,nil);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            println("Already authenticated");
        }
    }
    func reportScore(score:Int,leaderboardID:NSString) {
        var scoreReporter:GKScore = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier:"catchthategg01");
        scoreReporter.value = Int64(score);
        scoreReporter.context = 0;
        GKScore.reportScores([scoreReporter],{(error) -> Void in
            if let reportError = error {
                println("Unable to report score!\nError:\(error)");
            }
            else {
                println("Score reported successfully!");
            }
        });
    }

    func showLeaderboardOnViewController(viewController:UIViewController?, leaderboardID:NSString){
        if let containerController = viewController {
            var gamecenterController:GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController();
            gamecenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
            gamecenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards;
            gamecenterController.leaderboardIdentifier = "catchthategg01";
            viewController?.presentViewController(gamecenterController,animated:false,nil);
        }
    }
    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!){
        _gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false,nil);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: well, it is what it says: GameCenterUtils is not a UIViewController. And showLeaderboardOnViewController expects the viewController parameter to be a UIViewController, not a game center delegate.

Comment: So should I enter GameViewController for the parameter?

Comment: No, you need to find out what your UIViewController object is (the one that manages the SKView most likely) and pass that into the method.

Comment: but my GameViewController is defined as class GameViewController: UIViewController shouldn't that be the parameter to send?

Comment: Yes, certainly. Sorry, I mistook GameViewController for what you already pass in (GameCenterUtils).